Blazor .Net 8 OnAfterRenderAsync
In Blazor .Net 8 I cannot implement OnAfterRenderAsync. It gives me the error "No suitable method found to override".
I thought my project was corrupted so I created a new test project:
Blazor Web App
.Net 8
Authentication: none
Auto (Server and WebAssembly)
Per page/component
On Home.razor tried to add OnAfterRenderAsync and still get the same error. Here is the home page code. I tried InteractiveServer with prerendering and without prerendering. Same error.
@page "/"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@* @rendermode @(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false)) *@


<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

@code {
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync()
{

}
}

Has anyone else had this issue? I even updated to the latest Visual Studio before creating the new test project.

I realize I forgot to add the (bool firstRender) to the method. Everything is OK.
How to cancel/close this question now?
